# Tish'a Vetish'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred ninety-nine?

### ?תשעה ותשעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 299.

Once again, lazy gematria gets us nowhere with this one, but if I could find something interesting for 298, you certainly can for 299.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred ninety-eight entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not sure how much this is a Jewish fact per se, but Raavad, in his Seder HaKabbalah, [states](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46768&st=&pgnum=57) about Yeshu Hanotzri that "we have a reliable tradition that... **299** years after the building of the [second] Beis Hamikdash he was arrested, at age 36."

(Since the building of the second Beis Hamikdash was begun in 3408 since Creation, this comes to 3707, or 54 BCE. Raavad notes that non-Jewish history places this event several decades later, and argues that they deliberately postdated it in order to be able to claim that the Beis Hamikdash was destroyed not long afterwards.)

Answer (score 0):

Lazy gimatria does indeed get us something. It gets us some laughs.

http://www.gimatria.net/gimatria/299/ ayen sham.

Comment: Why is my internet security not letting me see that link?